# Installing Cent OS using Windows

Tags: linux, centos, linux-distributions, centos-5

I downloaded centos from their official bittorrent.It contained two iso files and md5sum.txt,sha1sum.txt and sha256sum.txt and also md5sum.txt.asc,sha1sum.txt.asc and sha256sum.txt.asc.
Now when I mount iso file to virtual drive there is no autoplay option.Can you tell me how to install it.I dont see any setup file?

Comment: Be aware that installing CentOS (or any other operating system) on your computer *typically* erases the existing Windows OS. It's certainly possible to have both (or more), but you have to know what you're doing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CentOS does not ship with a Windows installer. The easiest method is to burn the ISO to a CD/DVD (depending on the image you downloaded) and boot from that. [ImgBurn](http://www.imgburn.com) can help you with the burning process, simply select "Write image file to disc".

[image]

If you just want to test out CentOS, you may prefer [VirtualBox](http://www.virtualbox.org/). You can install CentOS from inside windows to a virtual disk file and run it inside it's own window. It will not run as fast as a bare metal install, but it will give you a good feel of the CentOS environment.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't your download a CD or DVD iso image that you have to burn to a **bootable** CD or DVD and boot from it to install?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use the [VirtualBox](http://virtualbox.org) solution already suggested by John T. It seems closer to your experience and it's a good way to test Linux.

Good luck.